# reference request : Numerical techniques for partial differential equations

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I want to learn how to solve parabolic,hyperbolic, and elliptic PDE's in any dimension numerically. Can anyone recommend a reference?

I recently read "Partial Differential Equations for Scientists and Engineers," by Stanley J Farlow, it was a good introduction for analytical methods such as Fourier transforming initial conditions in 1d heat flow, but I think it was not good for numerical and multi dimensional problems.

Comment: What level should the books be at, and what is the intended application? I rather like "Real-Time PDE-Constrained Optimization" by multiple authors, produced by SIAM, but this might not fit your use case at all.

Comment: I finished linear algebra and I am beginning analysis. I have experience solving Navier Stokes with newtons method, mostly over flat plates. 

What level would you recommend? I would like to avoid things like abstract topology and calculus on manifolds for now until I learn those!

Comment: First, this question is [probably a poor fit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113678/how-to-request-book-recommendations) for Math SE since it is primarily opinion-based and subject to change over time. The chatroom or twitter or some other social arena is probably a better place for it. That said, if you're avoiding calculus on manifolds and topology for now, is it safe to say you're more interested in applications than the numerical theory? If so, the PDE guides in whichever software tool you use are probably a good start and will link to their references.